# How can i Synchronize a Password from computer to local AD premises without locking your computer and unlock

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

if i change my password in my domain join computer to sync we need to lock and unlock with the new password.

How can I sync the password without having to do that?

I am trying:

```
$securepwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList domain\$pass, $Securepwd

Start-Process "notepad.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Windows\system32" -Credential $Credential
```

Please let me know if this

Comment: `klist purge` may work for services supporting Kerberos authentication however if the service supports only NTLM then I believe you must logoff and logon.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do this.

Here's why:

A decent amount of information is attached to a few low-level windows objects that are initialized either at boot or session start.

What's a session?  Well, a session starts when a user logs into *or unlocks* a given system.

When the session starts, a good amount of information will be cached, like, say:

- Your permissions as a user
- Your authentication information
- When your password expires

etc (actually listing all of these things would make it a massive answer).

To complete a change that involves both your box and the domain controller, you'll need to refresh this information.  It would be incredibly bad security to allow two different versions of you to talk to the domain controller.  The 'old' session with an out-of-date credential needs to be killed.

So you need to lock and unlock the computer to refresh your session, or otherwise force a reauthentication.

If you try to stop any of the processes that control authentication, such as lsass.exe, your computer will force a reboot immediately.